# How do we select the auto hideded value option first and then select the required options?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]How do we select the auto hideded value option first and then select the required options?
My HTML file has below:

Before Select domain:

```
div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class=" required-field" for="Domain">Domain</label>
                    <select autocomplete="off" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The 'Domain' field is required." id="Domain" name="Domain" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="Domain-error" aria-invalid="false">
                    <option value="">Select a domain...</option>
</select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-Domain-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-Domain-container" title="Select a domain...">Select a domain...</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Domain" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
```

After Domain name selection:

```
<select autocomplete="off" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-val="true" data-val-required="The 'Domain' field is required." id="Domain" name="Domain" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Select a domain...</option>
<option value="ABC.abc.com">ABC.abc.com</option></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-Domain-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-Domain-container" title="ABC.abc.com">ABC.abc.com</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

When we launch the website it will display the Domain Name drop down list and the option value as "Select a Domain". If I select the "Select a Domain" option the actual domain names will be displayed.( Means till i selelect the select domain option the valid domain name list will not displayed)

I am new to selenium so just i tried select the option using `find_element_by_id` and visible text option

I Tried the below python code. But its not working.

```
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Domain'));
print ([o.text for o in select_element.options])
select_element.select_by_visible_text('Select a domain...');
select_element1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Select a domain...'));
select_element.select_by_value('XYZ.xyz.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10 )
print('success')
```

I need to select as below sequence:

1. Select Domain button.
2. Next i need to select Auto hide Text "Select a Domain..." Option values.Then domain value will displays.
   ( Note: Utill Select a Domain... option the actual domain names are not listing)
   ( Another important point sometime even i slect  select domain auto hide the domain list not listing immediate
   May be required some waiting period)
3. Waiting period to load the domain list
4. In that select( Drop down list) "ABC.abc.com" domain value
5. Enter the login user name
6. Enter the password
7. Connect the page.

If any one sharing the full code for Python is appropriated

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in the `class` name in your `select` element before and after selecting `Select a domain...`

Before:

```
class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible valid"
```

After:

```
class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible"
```

It seem like you need `WebDriverWait` until the element `visibility_of_element_located`.

Import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Then try :

```
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Domain'));
print ([o.text for o in select_element.options])
select_element.select_by_visible_text('Select a domain...');
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Domain" and @class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible"]')))
slct = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Domain" and @class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible"]'));

#update here
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Domain" and @class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible"]').click()
time.sleep(1)

slct.select_by_visible_text('XYZ.xyz.com')
#slct.select_by_value('XYZ.xyz.com')
print('success')
```

Comment: Hi, Still I am not able to login. driver.implicitly_wait(10)
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Domain'));
print ([o.text for o in select_element.options])
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Select a domain...'));
select_element.select_by_value('ABC.abc.com')
print('success').a = driver.find_element_by_id('Username')
a.send_keys('username) Error:File "C:\Python374\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)

Comment: Updated the html code before domain selection and after domain selection

Comment: Updated answer, please try again.

Comment: Still the domain name I am not able select  May be this could be reason not sure <option value="">Select a domain...</option>   after updating manually  <option value="">Select a domain...</option>
<option value="ABC.abc.com">ABC.abc.com</option></select>

Comment: I used print statement(print ([o.text for o in slct.options]) to check before slct.select_by_visible_text('XYZ.xyz.com') line . Still it's printing ['Select a domain...'] only. The error i am getting as below selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: XYZ.xyz.com

Comment: Updated code, please try again. I add sleep and click the element before select `XYZ.xyz.com`

Comment: And try select use : `slct.select_by_value('XYZ.xyz.com')`

Comment: Thanks for your support. Sorry still i  am getting below errorselenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="Domain" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="Domain"> could not be scrolled into view